# How can I create a relative symlink given a relative path?

Tags: bash, shell-script, symlink

I would like to programmatically find the directory depth of a relative path. So for example the depth of `test/dir/hello` is 3

More specifically I would like the directory depth so that I can create a symlink to a file located to the parent directory.

I have the following 2 parameters: `${current_path}` and `${parent_file_to_lunk}`

How can I determine the directory depth in `${current_path}` so that I can create a relative symlnk to `${parent_file_to_lunk}`?

Something like this but with as many `../` as the directory depth:

```
cd ${current_path} ; ln -s ../$parent_file_to_link}
```

Comment: See also GNU `ln`'s `-r` option. With `bash -O extglob`, see `${current_path//+([^\/])/..}`

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create a `/home/kostas/test/dir/hello/link -> /home/kostas/file/to/link` actually expressed as a relative link `/home/kostas/test/dir/hello/link -> ../../../file/to/link`?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
parent_path=$(echo "$current_path"/ | sed -e "s|[^/]||g" -e "s|/|../|g")
cd "${current_path}" ; ln -s "${parent_path}${parent_file_to_link}"
```

This works simply by counting the slashes in `"${current_path}"`. 
The desired depth is one more than the number of slashes
(e.g., the depth of `test/dir/hello`, which contains two slashes, is 3),
so we simply add a slash: `echo "$current_path"/`.  Pipe it into `sed`. 
Since we’re manipulating slashes, it’s easier to use a character other than `/`
as the delimiter for `sed`’s `s` command; I like to use the vertical bar (`|`). 
`s|[^/]||g` finds all characters that are not slash
and replaces them with nothing. 
In other words, it deletes all characters except for the slashes. 
So, for the `"${current_path}"` value of `test/dir/hello`,
we `echo`’d `test/dir/hello/` and then chopped that down to `///`. 
Then `s|/|../|g"` changes every `/` into `../`, so we end up with `../../../`.

Note: this assumes that `"${current_path}"`
does not have any excess (unnecessary) slashes in it. 
For example, `test/dir//hello` and `test/dir/hello/`
are logically equivalent to `test/dir/hello`,
but they contain a misleading number of slash characters,
which will corrupt this process.

P.S. Always quote all shell variables unless you have a reason not to
and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.  Using braces
(as in `${variable_name}`) is not the equivalent to quoting.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```
file="/var/log/dmesg"
ln -s $file $(dirname $file)/../
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to create a:

```
/home/kostas/test/dir/hello/link -> /home/kostas/file/to/link
```

symlink (assuming `/home/kostas` is your current directory), but using a relative link, that is:

```
/home/kostas/test/dir/hello/link -> ../../../file/to/link
```

Then you could do (with GNU `ln`):

```
$ current_path=test/dir/hello
$ parent_file_to_lunk=file/to/link
$ ln -rsvt "$current_path/" "$parent_file_to_lunk"
‘test/dir/hello/link’ -> ‘../../../file/to/link’
```

Without GNU `ln`, but with GNU `bash -O extglob` or `zsh -o kshglob` or `ksh93`:

```
$ ln -s "${current_path//+([^\/])/..}/$parent_file_to_lunk" "$current_path/"
```

(note that it assumes that the components of `$current_path` are not symlinks themselves)